# how to plot the data of one column in the listA which is contained in a listB already

Tags: r, multithreading, file, plot, histogram

I have a problem of extracting data and list them together in R.

I have 24 files: `1.out` up to `24.out`. All 24 files contain same 5 columns, I wanna extract the 5th column of each file, then histogram all 24 files 5th column together.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.out")  
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i], header = TRUE))
```

I used this command to read the files, then I understand `temp[1]` will contain the first file name, but how to get into the file, and extract the 5th column. I tried:

```
file <- for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i[[5]]], header = TRUE))
```

Apparently, this is not correct. And after you extract all 5th column, how to histogram all columns in one time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning each table to a variable, you can loop through the files, read it, extract the fifth column, store them in a vector and then apply the histogram:

```
temp = list.files(pattern = "*.out")
hist(sapply(temp, function(fileName) read.table(fileName, header = TRUE)[5]))
```